# .fadeTo not able to delay to fade

Tags: jquery, function, click, fadeto

Trying to delay fade 500 to 1000, but when i change `.fadeTo('500', 1);` to `.fadeTo('1000', 1);` it's not delay to fade. Same timing, no difference between 500 to 1000.

**Jquery:**

```
$(".more-post").one("click", function () {

  $('.bottom-post').addClass('show-more').fadeTo('500', 0);

  setTimeout(function(){

    $('.bottom-post').addClass('show-more').fadeTo('500', 1);

  },4000);
});
```

This *Jquery* fade very fast, So how to fade delay more `.fadeTo('1000', 1);`. Want to fade more slow. Thanks.

Comment: .fadeTo('1000', 1) = appear in 1 Second(duration)  .fadeTo('1000', 0) fade away in 1 second (duration) . Try 2000(2 seconds) or 3000(3 seconds)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried `2000(2 seconds)` or `3000(3 seconds)` but no any change, fade very fast !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i removed the addClass() and changed **$(".more-post").one** to **$(".more-post").on** it started to work:

```js
$(".more-post").on("click", function() {

  $('.bottom-post').fadeTo(5000, 0);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="more-post">Click me to see the fade<div>
    <div class="bottom-post">Fade me slow<div>
```

**OR**

You can use **jqueryUI** toggleClass [here](http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/)

```js
$(".more-post").on("click", function() {
  $('.bottom-post').toggleClass('more-post', 3000).toggleClass("hide-post", 5000);
});
$(".hide-post").on("click", function() {
  $('.bottom-post').toggleClass("hide-post", 3000).toggleClass('more-post', 5000);
});
```

```css
.more-post {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hide-post {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="more-post">Click me to see slow fading<div>
  <p class="bottom-post hide-post">More stuff to be faded in</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set fadeTo('3000', 1).
Here 3000 means 3 seconds. You can increase it for more slow fading.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried 3000(3 seconds) but no any change, same fade very fast !

Comment: Ok. Try using hide() and show(). In this function, you can add parameters like fast, slow or give time in milliseconds. More details are here. http://api.jquery.com/hide/