# Delay fadeout for javascript tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tooltip in my code

```
<h6 class="right">Preferred Payment Method 
 <a href="#" class="tooltips" id="paymentHelp"><span class="question">?</span></a></h6>
```

and the follow javascript controls it

```
var paymentTooltip = document.getElementById("paymentHelp");
$(paymentTooltip).tooltip({ title: "TEXT <a href='#'>link here</a>", html: true, placement: "right" });
```

However, the problem I have is that the user does not have sufficient time to click the link inside. How can I delay the fadeOut so that this element is displayed for 5 seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fadeTo not able to delay to fade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472983/fadeto-not-able-to-delay-to-fade)

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like the [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Example usage: `$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );`

Thankfully, this is built in jQuery